# Как вывести ProcessorType из WMI Provider (Win32_Processor)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, wmi

Из описания на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx) в **Win32_Processor** есть поле **ProcessorType**.
Я пробую вывести это строками:

```
    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ProcessorType", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << "ProcessorType : " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;
```

Но оно выводит идентификатор, и исходя описания каждый идентификатор соответствует своему описанию, как конкретно само описание вывести?

```
   Other (1)
   Unknown (2)
   Central Processor (3)
   Math Processor (4)
   DSP Processor (5)
   Video Processor (6)
```

Выводиться число "3" а я хочу что бы "Central Processor", на ум приходит только сделать через case.

```
   Qualifiers: MappingStrings ("SMBIOS|Type 4|Processor Information|Processor Type")
```

Возможно это как то связано с моим вопросом, но я не знаю.
Программа для тренировки беру из примера [msdn-а](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте массив строк типа

```
const  char * procName[] =
{
    "Unknown",   // 0
    "Other", //  (1)
    "Unknown", //  (2)
    "Central Processor", //  (3)
    "Math Processor", //  (4)
    "DSP Processor", //  (5)
    "Video Processor", // (6)
};
```

и выводите

```
cout << procName[vtProp.uintVal] << endl;
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, меня устраивает если более лучших вариантов нет.

Comment: такой вопрос, использую такую конструкцию для похожей цели, но как сделать в этом массиве, что бы первый элемент начинался с "1" а не с "0" ?

Comment: Ну если позарез нужно - начните с нулевого `"Other"`, но используйте `procName[vtProp.uintVal-1]`.